# How long does Kilz need to dry before skim coating?

Tags: oil-based-paint

How long does oil based Kilz need to dry before I apply a skim coat texture to my ceilings?

I've recently scraped a popcorn texture down to drywall. Now I want to seal the porous surface before applying a skim coat.

My assumption is a full 24 hours is plenty of time to wait.

Comment: It depends largely on factors you haven't mentioned--ventilation, ambient humidity level, temperature. 24 hours is probably enough, but it may not be without proper handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best suggestion is to read the manufacturers instructions on usage. This information is often printed on the paint container label. You can also check at the manufacturers web site and look up the particular type of paint you are using.

For example: http://www.kilz.com/products/primer/kilz-complete
Click on the "PREPARATION, APPLICATION & CLEAN-UP" tab near bottom.

Answer (score 1):

From the link in the accepted answer, I found the following:

http://www.kilz.com/products/primer/kilz-original

Dry Time at 77°F (25°C), 50% RH
Dries to the touch in 30 minutes at 77°F (25°C) and 50% humidity.
Recoat or topcoat after 1 hour.